# Read String from file and store it locally, how to remove the line separator from the the text

Tags: java

I want to read from a file, the reading is successful, but because the file I am reading contains multiple lines the received string contains "\n" inside. How can I handle this in an elegant way? I don't want to just replace it after, is there a more optimal way to read from a file?

imput.txt

```
Anne big word random etc
another line here still input text
```

My Java Code:

```
    private static String readLineByLineJava8(String filePath) 
    {
        StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines( Paths.get(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) 
        {
            stream.forEach(s -> contentBuilder.append(s).append("\n"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return contentBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void ReadStringPrintOccurence() {
        String filePath = "imput.txt";
        String temp = readLineByLineJava8(filePath);
        String[] array = temp.split("\\r?\\n"); \\split in two arrays
        array = temp.split(" "); \\ further split by space
    }
```

I tried to work around it by splitting the array first by line separator and then by the space that is left between them to get the words in my string array. By doing this I get `array[4] = etc\nanother  and array[9] = text\n`.
What suggestions do you have for this?

Comment: use String::trim() https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want to achieve. You have a file containing multiple lines of text. What would you lie to do with this file? What's the point of readling line by line if you join all lines with a line separator? Why not just read the whole file at once then?

Comment: youre appending \n yourself stream.forEach(s -> contentBuilder.append(s).append("\n")); ???

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, You need to read the file preserving the newline characters.. and eventually collect them in a string.
I did same thing recently using a different Api in Files. Here is the code.

```
private static String readFileAsString(String filename) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
   return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
}
```

You can get more details on this post - https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-files-readallbytes-example/